# Custom hook with useRef and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I was reading a blog post which uses custom hooks and d3.
It consists of following code:

BarChart.js:

```
    import { useD3 } from './hooks/useD3';
    import React from 'react';
    import * as d3 from 'd3';

    function BarChart({ data }) {
      const ref = useD3(
        (svg) => {


          // console.log(svg)
          const height = 500;
          const width = 500;
          const margin = { top: 20, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40 };

          const x = d3
            .scaleBand()
            .domain(data.map((d) => d.year))
            .rangeRound([margin.left, width - margin.right])
            .padding(0.1);

          const y1 = d3
            .scaleLinear()
            .domain([0, d3.max(data, (d) => d.sales)])
            .rangeRound([height - margin.bottom, margin.top]);

          const xAxis = (g) =>
            g.attr("transform", `translate(0,${height - margin.bottom})`).call(
              d3
                .axisBottom(x)
                .tickValues(
                  d3
                    .ticks(...d3.extent(x.domain()), width / 40)
                    .filter((v) => x(v) !== undefined)
                )
                .tickSizeOuter(0)
            );

          const y1Axis = (g) =>
            g
              .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.left},0)`)
              .style("color", "steelblue")
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y1).ticks(null, "s"))
              .call((g) => g.select(".domain").remove())
              .call((g) =>
                g
                  .append("text")
                  .attr("x", -margin.left)
                  .attr("y", 10)
                  .attr("fill", "currentColor")
                  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
                  .text(data.y1)
              );

          svg.select(".x-axis").call(xAxis);
          svg.select(".y-axis").call(y1Axis);

          svg
            .select(".plot-area")
            .attr("fill", "steelblue")
            .selectAll(".bar")
            .data(data)
            .join("rect")
            .attr("class", "bar")
            .attr("x", (d) => x(d.year))
            .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
            .attr("y", (d) => y1(d.sales))
            .attr("height", (d) => y1(0) - y1(d.sales));
        },
        [data.length]
      );
      console.log("before svg render ",ref)
      return (
        <svg
          ref={ref}
          style={{
            height: 500,
            width: "100%",
            marginRight: "0px",
            marginLeft: "0px",
          }}
        >
          <g className="plot-area" />
          <g className="x-axis" />
          <g className="y-axis" />
        </svg>
      );
    }

    export default BarChart;
```

useD3.js hook:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import * as d3 from 'd3';

    export const useD3 = (renderChartFn, dependencies) => {
        const ref = React.useRef();

        React.useEffect(() => {
            renderChartFn(d3.select(ref.current));
            return () => {};
          }, dependencies);
        return ref;
    }
```

App.js:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import BarChart from './BarChart';
    import './App.css';

    const data = [
      {year: 1980, efficiency: 24.3, sales: 8949000},
      {year: 1985, efficiency: 27.6, sales: 10979000},
      {year: 1990, efficiency: 28, sales: 9303000},
      {year: 1991, efficiency: 28.4, sales: 8185000},
      {year: 1992, efficiency: 27.9, sales: 8213000},
      {year: 1993, efficiency: 28.4, sales: 8518000},
      {year: 1994, efficiency: 28.3, sales: 8991000},
      {year: 1995, efficiency: 28.6, sales: 8620000},
      {year: 1996, efficiency: 28.5, sales: 8479000},
      {year: 1997, efficiency: 28.7, sales: 8217000},
      {year: 1998, efficiency: 28.8, sales: 8085000},
      {year: 1999, efficiency: 28.3, sales: 8638000},
      {year: 2000, efficiency: 28.5, sales: 8778000},
      {year: 2001, efficiency: 28.8, sales: 8352000},
      {year: 2002, efficiency: 29, sales: 8042000},
      {year: 2003, efficiency: 29.5, sales: 7556000},
      {year: 2004, efficiency: 29.5, sales: 7483000},
      {year: 2005, efficiency: 30.3, sales: 7660000},
      {year: 2006, efficiency: 30.1, sales: 7762000},
      {year: 2007, efficiency: 31.2, sales: 7562000},
      {year: 2008, efficiency: 31.5, sales: 6769000},
      {year: 2009, efficiency: 32.9, sales: 5402000},
      {year: 2010, efficiency: 33.9, sales: 5636000},
      {year: 2011, efficiency: 33.1, sales: 6093000},
      {year: 2012, efficiency: 35.3, sales: 7245000},
      {year: 2013, efficiency: 36.4, sales: 7586000},
      {year: 2014, efficiency: 36.5, sales: 7708000},
      {year: 2015, efficiency: 37.2, sales: 7517000},
      {year: 2016, efficiency: 37.7, sales: 6873000},
      {year: 2017, efficiency: 39.4, sales: 6081000},
    ]

    function App() {
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <header className="App-header">
            <BarChart data={data} />
          </header>
        </div>
      );
    }

    export default App;
```

When BarChart runs, it calls useD3 hook before its render method. Inside useD3 hook, code runs and after the return ref; line, the callback of the useEffect hook should run. This is my thought process, but apparently react doesnt work like that. Can someone enlighten me?
When exactly does the useEffect callback run?

Comment: The code in the question is too fragmentary for us to help you with it. Please put more context in the question. Note that your whole question (including any necessary code) has to be **in** your question, not just linked. Three reasons: People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you; some sites are blocked for some users; and links rot, making the question and its answers useless to people in the future. Please put a [mcve] **in** the question. (Please read the link for details, the details matter.)

Comment: More: [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect)

> The function passed to useEffect will run after the render is committed to the screen

So the function passed to `useEffect` will run **after** the rendering of the component.

Note that this function can **optionally** returns a [clean-up function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#cleaning-up-an-effect). This function will be called immediately before the next effect.

> the previous effect is cleaned up before executing the next effect

Here is a small [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tsxvgi?file=src/App.js)

```js
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('effect ' + count);

    return () => console.log('cleanup effect ' + count);
  }, [count]);

  console.log('render ' + count);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Count = {count}</span>
      &nbsp;
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        +1
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

We can see that `effect` is effectively printed after `render`.

Comment: right. somehow i assumed that the useD3's useeffect callback triggers when the execution of useD3 is over. it confused me, because useEffect was not "directly" inside the BarChart component.

Comment: `useD3` is just a [custom hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#using-a-custom-hook). it's simply a function starting with `use` keyword that can call other hooks